# Spring Security remember-me services

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I configured Spring Security with remember-me option.

```
 <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
   <security:http pattern="/login.html"  security="none"/>
   <security:http pattern="/signup.html"  security="none"/>
  <security:http pattern="/scripts/**" security="none"/>
  <security:http pattern="/styles/**" security="none"/>
  <security:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>

  <security:http disable-url-rewriting="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">
  <security:session-management>
  <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" max-sessions="10"/>
  </security:session-management>
  <security:form-login login-page="/login.html" login-processing-url="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" default-target-url="/"/> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
  <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
  <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
    </security:http>
```

and then the services itself:

```
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
      <property name="tokenRepository" ref="myTokenRepository" />
      <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
      <property name="key" value="myRememberMeKey" />
      <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="myTokenRepository" class="com.mytwitter.web.security.MyTokenRepository">
  </bean>
```

I can see in my schema that tokens are inserted/updated/deleted in database. so this is not an issue.

but sign on fails:

```
2012-02-13 13:35:56,497 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Remember-me cookie detected - 2065616 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,498 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "series" : "Ww2a8WsycNlGWxZRDubTnA=="} in db.collection: mytwitter.rememberMeTokens - 2065617 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,500 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0' - 2065619 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,500 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Refreshing persistent login token for user 'aaaa', series 'Ww2a8WsycNlGWxZRDubTnA==' - 2065619 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,510 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - calling update using query: { "series" : "Ww2a8WsycNlGWxZRDubTnA=="} and update: { "$set" : { "tokenValue" : "u0m7/ze3DpDInv27+JuPdQ==" , "date" : { "$date" : "2012-02-13T11:35:56.500Z"}}} in collection: rememberMeTokens - 2065629 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,511 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - findOne using query: { "nickname" : "aaaa"} in db.collection: mytwitter.users - 2065630 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,512 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Remember-me cookie accepted - 2065631 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,512 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider - 2065631 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,513 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0' - 2065632 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,514 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as AuthenticationManager rejected Authentication returned by RememberMeServices: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@5195b417: Principal: com.mytwitter.web.security.AuthUser@15880543; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'; invalidating remember-me token - 2065633 
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: The presented RememberMeAuthenticationToken does not contain the expected key
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(RememberMeAuthenticationProvider.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
2012-02-13 13:35:56,529 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful. - 2065648 
2012-02-13 13:35:56,529 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie - 2065648
```

Actually what I do see as weird is that in line `2012-02-13 13:35:56,514` which prints Authentication object, SessionId is null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

The problem solved.

I should have add "key" property in remember-me parameter as well.

```
 <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" key="myRememberMeKey" />
```

and it should be the key with the same name as in "remeberMeServices" bean.